# Load Titan graph with Gremlin

Tags: cassandra, titan, gremlin

Im toataly new with TitanDB.
Im using it with cassandra & Java:

Configuration file:

```
storage.backend=cassandra
storage.hostname=@CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_INNER_ADDRESS@
```

Java code:

```
TitanGraph tg = TitanFactory.open(/*the configuration above*/);
if (tg.isOpen()) {
    TitanManagement tm = tg.getManagementSystem();
    PropertyKey key = tm.getPropertyKey(name);
    /* The rest of the nice working code */
}
```

The Java code works fine, I can query the graph, do CRUD operations etc...

Now, I want to query the graph without using JAVA.
At first I tried using `cqlsh` there I saw this:

```
Keyspace titan
--------------
edgestore        graphindex        system_properties        systemlog  txlog
edgestore_lock_  graphindex_lock_  system_properties_lock_  titan_ids
```

after digging in it I understood that I need to use tool like `gremlin` to query the TitanDB properly.
But when I'm tring to connect the TitanDB via gremlin I get this message:

```
    gremlin> TitanFactory.open("cassandra.local")
No such property: TitanFactory for class: groovysh_evaluate
Display stack trace? [yN] y
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TitanFactory for class: groovysh_evaluate
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:51)
        at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:67)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter$evaluate.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:152)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:114)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:88)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:100)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:66)
        at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.console.Console.<init>(Console.java:60)
        at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.console.Console.main(Console.java:102)
```

**My question is:**
How can I get Gremlin to know TitanFactory - and finally how can I work with gremlin on my existing TitanDB v. 0.5.4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you downloaded Gremlin 2.x from the TinkerPop site, I would expect to see the error you had because it does not have the Titan libraries on the classpath.

You should get the Titan 0.5.4 download from thinkaurelius and follow along with the Gremlin Shell documentation.

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/getting-started.html#_downloading_titan_and_running_the_gremlin_shell

Comment: How did you install titan dependencies?